# How to add multiple meta boxes in wordpress using the users input for any post in a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

What i am actually trying to do here is : 
- I have a custom post type to add videos.  
- Now in every video a user can add multiple fields for a video for eg.  
  -- I have a video on which there will be multiple overlays containing (title, desc, button , link etc) and the number of overlays are completely dynamic so the user should be able to set it for every video. 
 -- So if the user says 5, then the user should be get 5 title, desc, button fields to add

I can add this statically for a particular amount, but how do i make this dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever try Meta box plugin, it's free in wordpress.org

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/ - No
I will try this right away

Comment: @HàLink i checked out the plugin, ..can you direct me to a tutorial where i can do something like that since i am creating a plugin and would like to have it in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own fields in your plugin, it is not difficult, you just need to know what you want to put in your post type ... 
To add your fields you need to know jQuery to add more fields dynamically... 
No need for another plugin created because you'd have many things that would use...

```
<?php 
add_meta_box( "my-new-meta", "Video Options", "metas_form", "your_post_type_name", "normal", "high")
function metas_form(  $post ){
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key_text', true ); 
    ?>
    <div>
        <label id="my_field">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="my_field" name="my_field" value="<?php echo $meta_value ?>">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="field_nonce" id="field_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ); ?>" />
    <?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_fn' );
function save_fn( ) {
    global $post, $post_id, $typenow;
    if ( $typenow  == 'your_post_type_name' && isset( $_POST ) ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    if ( !isset( $_POST['field_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['field_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) return $post_id;
    $meta_value = $_POST['my_field'];
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key_text', $meta_value );

}
```

}